# Is there a slicing operator for Matlab (Octave) structs to convert them to an array or vector of scalars and back?

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, struct, octave

In Matlab or GNU Octave I'd like to do something like this:

```
x=struct('a',1,'b',2,'c',[1 2;3 4])
y=x(:) % array-ification of a struct
save -ascii y.txt y
z=load('y.txt')
x(:)=z % struct-ification of an array
```

I want to serialize/pickle a structure and recreate it later, allowing easy read/save/manipulate in other languages. I'd prefer the intermediate form to be ascii text rather than binary to facilitate human reading/editing/debugging.

Am I forgetting some clever (:)-like slicing for structs or cell arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is something like:

```
x = struct('a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', [1 2; 3 4])
save('y.txt', '-struct', 'x', '-ascii')
```

But I do not think you can easily recreate it from the resulting file: there is data loss (the fieldnames are lost).  If you don't use the -ascii option, it can be fully recreated using:

```
save('y.mat', '-struct', 'x')
y = load('y.mat')
isequal(x, y) % returns true
```

Additionally load can only load a rectangular array of numbers of ASCII text (see http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/save.html and http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/load.html for the limitations). If you wish to keep the fields of the struct in your serialized form, you might look into the "fieldnames" function.

Comment: You're right that I can't figure out how to reassign elements of the array to fieldnames using a hard-coded schema. I can't even figure out how to read in the resulting y.txt ascii file due to inconsistent column lengths. I guess what I'm looking for isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is :),

```
x=struct('a',1,'b',2,'c',[1 2;3 4])
y=reshape([fieldnames(x) struct2cell(x)]',1,[]) % array-ification of a struct

z=struct(y{:}) % struct-ification of an array
```

> y =
>
> 'a'    [1]    'b'    [2]    'c'    [2x2 double]
>
> z =
>
> a: 1
>
> b: 2
>
> c: [2x2 double]

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to easily save the resulting cell array using the -ascii option. But this gets me closer.